# Upload thousands of csv and merge them together

Tags: r

I need to upload about 21 000 csv files from my computers directory.
They are structured like so: 2005_4.csv where 2005 is the year and 4 is the day of the year. I have those files for more than 20 years.  Obvisouly I can't load them all one by one and have no idea how to do that operation.
They are all structured the same way though like so:

```
structure(list(A08B08_...79.4945...48.4148..296.....2.68 = c("A08E31_ -79.4679 48.4254 278. 2.77", "A09A03_ -79.4848 48.4178 301. 2.66", "A12B01_ -79.4944 48.4146 296. 2.69", "A12B01_ -79.4944 48.4146 296. 2.69", "A12B01_ -79.4944 48.4146 296. 2.69", "B12RJ52 -78.6642 49.4051 275. 1.72", "B12YE02 -78.8871 49.2079 335. 1.87", "ESB14M3 -79.1944 48.4529 277. 2.83", "F04F51_ -79.2888 48.4951 299. 2.71", "F09B02_ -79.3472 48.4472 273. 2.81", "F09J11_ -79.3461 48.4964 273. 2.80", "F12I01_ -79.1944 48.4496 280. 2.82", "F18P01_ -79.2628 48.4395 273. 2.83", "H05Z02_ -79.3870 48.5190 273. 2.78", "H08Z03_ -79.3712 48.5175 273. 2.79", "H08Z09_ -79.2122 48.4836 272. 2.85", "H13Z07_ -79.4915 48.5238 302. 2.62", "H13Z08_ -79.4914 48.5239 302. 2.62", "H13Z25_ -79.2107 48.4825 272. 2.85", "H18Z27_ -79.4014 48.5175 284. 2.73", "SC14F10 -79.4684 48.4269 278. 2.77", "A12B01_ -79.4944 48.4146 296. 2.69", "F04F51_ -79.2888 48.4951 299. 2.71", "F09Y06_ -79.3442 48.4690 276. 2.79", "H05Z02_ -79.3870 48.5190 273. 2.78", "J20A14_ -79.3595 48.5011 275. 2.79", "J20F05_ -79.3220 48.5038 272. 2.81", "J21A01_ -79.4791 48.4201 290. 2.71", "J21A06_ -79.3511 48.5180 273. 2.79", "J21F16_ -79.3619 48.4413 274. 2.80", "F03K08_ -79.2996 48.4407 305. 2.68", "J22A02_ -79.4816 48.4229 290. 2.71", "J22A12_ -79.3709 48.5176 273. 2.79", "J22A13_ -79.3526 48.4922 274. 2.80", "J22A36_ -79.3838 48.4229 298. 2.70", "J22A43_ -79.4866 48.4452 291. 2.70", "J22A50_ -79.4303 48.4779 356. 2.42", "J22A66_ -79.3386 48.3582 303. 2.68", "J22F05_ -79.3455 48.4663 272. 2.81", "J22F10_ -79.2696 48.4380 272. 2.83", "J22F11_ -79.3005 48.4410 300. 2.70", "J20F05_ -79.3222 48.5037 272. 2.81", "S22SD01 -73.8309 45.5396 37. 3.00", "S22BP01 -73.6831 45.6040 39. 3.07", "S22PP01 -73.5205 45.6910 16. 2.97", "S22SE01 -73.6260 46.2881 303. 0.54", "S22SE02 -73.6192 46.3146 346. 0.43", "S22SC01 -73.7259 46.2531 259. 0.55", "S22NO01 -75.0557 46.4020 287. -0.12", "O22HM33 -79.9951 46.1177 212. 1.35")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

In an ideal world, I would have a single file for each year where each Id has a single year and date pasted to it!

Hope I was clear. Hope someone can help me!

Comment: What sort of memory footprint are we talking about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import multiple .csv files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
# get a vector of all filenames
myfiles <- list.files("path/to/directory/")

# loop over files names, reading them in to R and saving each data.frame as an element in a list
n <- length(myfiles)
datalist <- vector(mode="list", length=n)
for(i in 1:n) {
    cat("importing file", i, ":", myfiles[i], "\n")
    datalist[[i]] <- read.csv(myfiles[i])
}

# combine files, use idcol argument to keep track of original csv file
all_data <- data.table::rbindlist(datalist, idcol=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi @DanY! Thanks for your answer! That seems to partially work, but there is a slight problem, I need to be able to identify the date and year of the data. Now the files are just on top of one another. Is there a way to add two columns, one that is year and one that is the doy?

Comment: After the `for` loop, you can name the list elements by their file names using `names(datlist) <- myfiles`.  Then the `idcol=TRUE` part of the code will create a unique identifier using the file names instead of simply an integer.  You may then want to split the year and month information into separate variables using something like `str_split()` from the `stringr` package.